# Session not saving for whole site

Tags: php, html, apache, session

I got a really weird problem with the php session functions.

First of all: it works only in certain browsers. Like random selected: FF on windows, but not on Mac, Chrome on both platforms, safari doesnt work IE does however.

I have a login script, where I create a session if the login data is correct:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = $user_info['username'];

echo "<pre>";
print_r($_SESSION);
echo "</pre>";
```

When I do print_r in the login script, after setting the session  variables, it works for all browsers. But after redirecting the user to the main site, the session is empty for some browsers....

I never had such a problem and I really dont know what to do...

Comment: When you say "redirecting the user to the main site", is this a different site? How are you redirecting them?

Comment: Its not completely clear what you ask. Do you start every page with `session_start();`?

Comment: Yes of course I do. And its the same domain and the same server, not even a subdomain, sorry for not clarifying that.

Comment: A debug question - does `session_id()` on the login page give you the same ID on the other pages?

Comment: Where does the data of this array comes from,  $user_info['username'];. You need to define this first

Comment: Its from a database. But thats not the point, it doesnt work if i put a static "test" as the value. As I said, in the login script, all session variables got the correct value. But some browsers(?) dont save the session variables...

Answer (score 1):

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = $user_info['username'];

echo "<pre>";
print_r($_SESSION);
echo "</pre>";
```

If this is what starts every page, I can understand you dont see anything anymore after the refresh, cause simply, what you do is you start your session, you set the $_SESSION variable Username to $User_info with the variable username. And you do that every time.

But consider this: your variable isn't specified at all at this point. Maybe you set it up when you logged in, however, you clear it inmideatly on the next refresh, cause you tell it use that $user_info['username'] again. In this case, with nothing called on forhand, it will be an empty variable. Thus, your username will be blank.

Your session['username'] will also be blank, because you tell it to take that information.

Since you set it when you log in, there is no need to respecify it, cause your session['username'] is already set

**edit**

so I ask now, what do you put to your database? Do you save the SessionId in your DB? Cause then you can make something like this.

```
session_start();

$Session=session_id();  
$result1 = LoadSessionData($Session);
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result1);
if($count=="0"){
    $Time=time();
    $Ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    StartSessionData($Session,$Time,$Ip);
    $_SESSION['Username'] = '';
}else{
    while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){       
        $UserName = $row1['GebruikerNaam'];
        if ($UserName == ""){
            $_SESSION['Username'] = '';
        }
        $Time=time();
        $Time_check=$Time-3600;
        $Ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        OnlineChecker($Session,$UserName,$Time,$Ip);
    }
}
```

I hope you can follow it, but i ll try to explain. It checks if the sessionId is in the database, if not, add the session id in the database together with timestamp, ip and session username, which is set to blank.

Else, i check what i get back, if it has a username, use that. If it's blank, the sessionusername will remain blank, cause it checks later on with that username if I am logged in. Then I update the database with the username, time, etc.

Comment: I just use that code in the login script. On any other site i just use print_r so see if it works

Comment: Could you post then how you start every page? Cause your error might be there then. Technically, you show us now working code :)

Comment: basically just session_start(); on every page. I dont save anything session related in the database. If the session expires, the user has to login again.